# jQuery.click on a div that hasn't yet loaded

Tags: php, jquery, html

I dynamically load a div on page Leagues.php with a button like this:

```
$("#leaguesSelectionTable th").click(function(){
    var leagueSelect = $(this).attr('id');
    if ($('#leaguesTable').length){
        $("#loadLeagueTables").empty();
        $("#loadLeagueTables").load("php/leagueTable.php?leagueSelect="+encodeURIComponent(leagueSelect));
    }
    else {
        $("#loadLeagueTables").load("php/leagueTable.php?leagueSelect="+encodeURIComponent(leagueSelect));
    }
});
```

This loads a table based on which button I pressed, using leagueTable.php to handle all of that. Once that table is loaded, (a bunch of leagues) I want to then be able to click on a row from this table and following the same logic, display the team table.

```
    $("#assoc_league tr").click(function(){
    var teamSelect = $(this).attr('id');
    if ($('#teamsTable').length){
        $("#loadTeamTables").empty();
        $("#loadTeamTables").load("php/teamTable.php?teamSelect="+encodeURIComponent(teamSelect));
    }
    else {      
        $("#loadTeamTables").load("php/teamTable.php?teamSelect="+encodeURIComponent(teamSelect));
    }
});
```

I think the problem is that since table #assoc_league is not yet present, this does not work. I tried an alert and don't get any response. This jQuery is in the same file attached to Leagues.php. Any ideas how to approach this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your table has been added dynamically to the DOM, all the events for this `table` and child elements inside it will not be avaliable. In this case, you need to use **[event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)** :

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a
>   parent element, that will fire for all children matching a selector,
>   whether those children exist now or are added in the future.

```
$('#loadLeagueTables').on('click', '#assoc_league tr', function() {
    // Your code here
});
```

Comment: Can I ask the difference between '#assoc_league tr' and "#assoc_league tr"? When to use which quotes?

Comment: No difference here. You can use either quotes or double quotes in this case.